# Write excel file to file stream with nodejs and download it with api call in browser

Tags: node.js, excel, exceljs

I am stuck at problem on how to write excel file to filestream and download it in browser.. I can only create new file in server but this is not what I want.. I don't want to create in on server (ok if it must be created then i also want to delete it when user downloads it in browser).

But I can't achieve the download..

So the general idea is that I read the csv file, than parse the data.

I also read a template Excele file which I overwrite and write it to the file stream. When I call the get API, then I can the download starts (I will integrate it in Angular app later)..

I am using Exceljs npm package.

I don't have any errors but code is not working as I want

I uploaded whole code in github so you can easily see the code and duplicate my code.

https://github.com/zigax1/mean-generate-download-excel/tree/master

My excel-builder script:

```
export const generateExcel = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    await csvParse();
    res.setHeader("Content-disposition", `attachment;`);
    res.contentType(
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    );

    return res.status(200).json("Success");
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json("False");
  }
};

const csvParse = async () => {
  fs.createReadStream("./content/TestCsv.csv")
    .pipe(csv.parse())
    .on("error", (error: any) => console.log("Error"))
    .on("data", (row: any) => {
      let line: any = String(row);
      line = line.split(";");
      //let parsedData = line[0];
      let parsedData = line;
      allParsedData.push(parsedData);
    })
    .on("end", (rowCount: any) => {
      let test = allParsedData.toString();
      generateFile(test);
    });
};

const generateFile = (data: any) => {
  return new Promise<fs.ReadStream>((resolve, reject) => {
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

    workbook.xlsx.readFile("./utilities/template.xlsx").then(() => {
      workbook.xlsx.writeFile("./content/Test.xlsx").then(
        () => {
          let stream = fs.createReadStream("./content/Test.xlsx");
          stream.on("close", () => {
            fs.unlink("./content/Test.xlsx", (error) => {
              if (error) {
                throw error;
              }
            });
          });

          resolve(stream);
        },
        (err) => {
          throw err;
        }
      );
    });
  });
};
```

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');

function exportCSVFile(res, path, data) {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(path + ".csv");
    ws.on("finish", function () {
        res.download(path + ".csv", () => {
            fs.unlinkSync(path + ".csv");
        });
    });
    csv.write(data, {headers: true}).pipe(ws);
}
```

You use this export csv function for your response